# VBA Do while Loop in For Loop executes only once

Tags: vba, loops, for-loop, do-loops

I have an issue where my Do While Loop in a For Loop only executes once. I try to achieve the following:

I have a bunch of excel files (*.xlsm), located in the same folder which contains data for some employees and I want to loop through each of them and get a certain number. So far so good. The issue becomes when I want to "change" the employee name.

Given the following code:

```
Set FldrPicker = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)

With FldrPicker
    .Title = "Select A Target Folder"
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    If .Show <> -1 Then GoTo NextCode
    myPath = .SelectedItems(1) & "\"
End With

NextCode:
myPath = myPath
If myPath = "" Then GoTo ResetSettings

myExtension = "*.xlsm"
myFile = Dir(myPath & myExtension)        

For i = 1 To 3
    xCallsEin = 0
    xMa = wb.Sheets(2).Cells(i, 1)
    MsgBox xMa
    Do While myFile <> ""
        Set wb2 = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=myPath & myFile)
        DoEvents

        xCallsEinTemp = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(xMa, wb2.Sheets(1).Range(Columns(2), Columns(6)), 4, 0)

        xCallsEin = xCallsEin + xCallsEinTemp

        wb2.Close SaveChanges:=False
        DoEvents
        myFile = Dir
        wb1.Sheets(1).Cells(i + 6, 2) = xCallsEin        
    Loop        
Next i
```

The Do while code executes only once, for the first `i` in the For Loop.
I figured out because the `myFile` variable is empty by the time the first do while loop is done.
I need help on how to set the `myFile` variable to something again in order for the do while loop to execute as many times as the for loop.

Comment: Turn it around: put the `For` inside the `Do` loop.

Comment: So this `MsgBox()` really comes only once? - `MsgBox xMa`?

Comment: Use `Option Explicit` and declare your variables. And avoid `GoTo`, which looks terrible.

Comment: but how do you prorperly error handle in vba without GoTo? o_O

Comment: @CindyMeister i tried turning them around, doesn't work. I receive the error if the `myPath` was changed, renamed or deleted...
@Vityata the `MsgBox()` appears 3 times, yet the values only populate for one of the 3 cells...

Comment: @IonuţSanda - have you tried pressing F8, going step-by-step and seeing what happens?

Comment: @DougCoats `On Error GoTo` isn't a `GoTo` statement, it's an `On Error` statement

Comment: @IonuţSanda - consider writing `myFile = Dir(myPath & myExtension)` outside the Do-While loop.

Comment: @MathieuGuinDon  I was being facetious

Comment: @DougCoats I was being... a pedantic pain in the neck ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Do While...Loop` exits when `myFile` is empty. So at the next `For...Next` loop iteration, `myFile` is *still* empty and thus the second `For` loop iteration doesn't enter the `Do While` loop, because its exit condition is met right away.

Consider moving this line:

```
myFile = Dir(myPath & myExtension)
```

First thing inside the `For...Next` loop.

...then fix the looping logic so that you don't need to re-process each file 3 times.

Comment: Hi @Mathieu Guidon. I've moved the `myFile = Dir(myPath & myExtension)` into the For loop and it worked perfectly.
Unfortunately, I need to re-process every file multiple times because the purpose of the macro is to gather information for a list of employees.